BIRT Runtime version compatibility issue with BIRT Report
I am new to BIRT report. I am able to design report and run as viewer, but when I am trying to call it with spring boot API I am facing-
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The design file  has error and can not be run.
org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserException: The report file of version "3.2.25" is invalid for it is greater than the latest supported one.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.ModuleState.parseAttrs(ModuleState.java:114)
... 73 more. I am facing version compatibility issues with BIRT dependency version and Report design version.
I want to know the compatible BIRT runtime dependencies with Report version <3.2.25>, or If any other solution that may resolve the above issue.
I tried changing the dependencies but not able to match that support the report version 3.2.25.
Thanks in advance!!

In most cases it should suffice if you edit the file and replace 3.2.25 with 3.2.23 before opening it.

It seems you're using a pretty old version of BIRT. can you update to some newer one ? you can have a llok to the releases here https://download.eclipse.org/birt/updates/release/latest/

CHANGING THE VERSION 3.2.25 with 3.2.23 resolves this issue. We can go to the XML source format of the report file and find this line initially as-
and change the version accordingly.
